# Object not recognized in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to make a bar graph and add to it the percentages of each category. However when I try to run the code I get the following error message:

```
Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomLabel,  : 
  object 'share' not found
```

Here is my code:

```
base3 %>%
  group_by(country.x) %>% 
  summarise(total=sum(cost)) %>%
  mutate(countrygroup=sapply(country.x,cathegorize), countries=sapply(country.x,reverse_cathegorize), share=total/sum(total)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(countries,total),y=total,fill=countrygroup),colour = 'black', alpha = 0.5,stat="identity")+
  geom_label(aes(x=reorder(countries,total),y=share),label = paste0(round((share), 3)*100, '%'))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A couple potential reasons:

1. Your variable `share` isn't being created properly in `mutate()`; when you just run lines 1-4 (so, before `ggplot()`), what does your dataset look like?
2. When you call `round((share), 3)`, ggplot doesn't know that you're talking about a variable, since it's outside of `aes()`; try `round((.$share), 3)`